# Setting up netbeans for primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am having problems with NetBeans and primefaces.

I need to know which file to download from primefaces.org http://www.primefaces.org/downloads. I use to download the 4.0 zip in community downloads, I tried updating to 6.0 and that didn't work. And now I cant even download 4.0 zip;

Basically I need an updated process on how to set up primefaces in NetBeans.,

When you try to download 4.0 .zip in community downloads, you get a 404 error.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same here. You can download the .jar files, there are up. Here is the upgrade guides for primefaces. https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/wiki/Migration-Guide

or add to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>  
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>  
    <version>4.0</version>  
</dependency>
```

Comment: You are welcome. Then you can still accept the answer.

Comment: which .jar binary or sources.

Comment: The best is both.

Comment: The link didn't help

Comment: What do I need to do to netbeans

Comment: For add to the netbeans Projekt? https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=jsS_cRbNv3o

Comment: I am getting this error from netbeans, the primefaces library is not set up properly

Comment: Open a New question with a complete description. And post your other libraries

Comment: If you have a pom.xml, yes.

Comment: Well if it's that easy why not. Thanks man, can I keep u as a personal helper lol.  Thanks again.

Comment: If you will upgrade, des.